# What level of cryptographic review has the current Monero protocol received?

Tags: ring-signatures, eddsa, curve25519

What are the backgrounds of the members of the Monero Research Lab? What amount of known peer review have their publications received?

1. Independent of Monero itself, how much Cryptographic review has their been of EdDSA for signatures, and Curve25519 for DH key exchange?
2. How much review has there been of ring signatures of the type used by Monero and other CryptoNote coins?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The members of the MRL have all earned their PhD (which fact the website does not reflect at present) in various mathematical fields.

Their publications have received various levels of peer review. The RingCT paper, for instance, has been submitted to the Ledger journal, and has been approved to be included in the first edition.

To answer the two other questions you posed:

1. Massive amounts of review. Perhaps the best way to illustrate this is to link you to the list of things that [implement Curve25519](https://ianix.com/pub/curve25519-deployment.html), and that [implement Ed25519 / EdDSA](https://ianix.com/pub/ed25519-deployment.html).
2. Quite a bit of review. As an example, take a read through [Andrew Poelstra's answer to this StackExchange question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/29471/are-there-any-true-anonymous-cryptocurrencies/29473). It is enlightening.

Answer (score 2):

2. I consider the `Monero protocol` a reviewed version of the `Cryptonote protocol`, one of the first papers from the [Monero Research Labs](https://lab.getmonero.org/) was [reviewed](https://downloads.getmonero.org/whitepaper_review.pdf) version of the original [Cryptonote whitepaper](https://cryptonote.org/whitepaper.pdf). Their subsequent works are improvements upon the original protocol like the [minimum mixin](https://lab.getmonero.org/pubs/MRL-0004.pdf) required for a transaction.